# Why does someone need to install Linux(Debian/fedora) distribution inside Android?

Tags: linux

I need some ideas from you. Why does someone need to install Linux distribution (Debian/Fedora) inside an android phone using android apps like 'Linux Deploy'?

Comment: [This is a nice one .I think this will be helpful ](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/things-consider-linux-smartphone-os/)

Answer (score 1):

[This article has some good explanations.](http://www.techradar.com/how-to/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/how-to-install-linux-on-an-android-phone-1322579)

eg.

> We can think of many reasons why you'd want a proper Linux PC in your pocket. You can, for example, use it to power a LAMP server that can run web apps and serve web pages. If you're a network admin, you can install your favourite Linux tools and turn the smartphone into a portable network troubleshooting or pen-testing device.